# Calling function from different js file

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have been inspecting code of one chrome extension file (adds couple of buttons into the website), and noticed that this extension had separate js files 'content.js' and 'buttons.js', in buttons.js there were functions which returned button elements with style, and in content.js they were used, when I was building my extension I had to make the functions within the content.js otherwise they weren't working. I also haven't noticed any kind of 'imports' in his files - they just seem to work just like that. But I also see jquery.min.js file in his extension which is hardly readable, could it somehow be linked from within there? If yes how could I achieve this in my extension files?

buttons.js:

```
const createButtonOne = () => {
    const button = document.createElement('button')
    button.classList.add("Button")
    const buttonText = document.createTextNode('TEXT')
    button.appendChild(buttonText)
    return button
}
```

content.js:

```
const ButtonOne = createButtonOne()
```

Comment: Use multi-file search for the names of these files to find where they are used. Usually it's in manifest.json or in some html file. In manifest.json it'll be a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). In html it'll be a script tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.appendChild(ButtonOne)
```

It is quite possible that the extension is using an imported library such as jQuery to create the buttons. If this is the case, then you could achieve the same functionality by importing the jQuery library into your extension. To do this, you would add a  tag in your extension manifest file that points to the jQuery library, like so:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["jquery.min.js", "buttons.js", "content.js"]
  }
]
```

Once this is done, you can then use the jQuery library to create the buttons in your content.js file. For example:

```
const createButtonOne = () => {
    return $('<button>TEXT</button>').addClass('Button');
}

const ButtonOne = createButtonOne()
$(document.body).append(ButtonOne)
```